# Android ListView with different layouts for each row (that can survive sorting)

Tags: android, sorting, android-layout, listview

It's a little tricky one i think,

I have a ListView that I sort in few different sorting using compare.
I want to do 2 things:

**Different Layout Question**

1. Set some of the records to different layout.
2. Sort differently the top 3 records and the rest of the records.

To change the layout by the record type i do this :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        if (businesses.get(pos).isTop())
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.business_model_top, null);
        else
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.business_model, null);
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't survive sorting.
If for example the 2nd and 5th row are on the different layout, the will remain as this layout even if the records moved to other positions.

**Second question**

The reason i want to do it is related to the other question, 
I would like to have 2 sorting of two parts of the listview as if :

1-row one
2-row two

### 3-row three

4-row four
5-row five
.
.
.
.

When i sort by something, i want to keep the 3 top rows at the top (sorted) and the rest of the list items sorted as well but below.

I hope all is clear

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you google the first question. There is already a lot of information available about how to create different layouts for each row. For the second question, you should put the top three rows in their own parent view...either a second ListView or perhaps just another static layout, such as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: I couldn't find solutions that includes sorting.

Comment: In general, breaking a problem into smaller problems is a critical skill for all programmers. This is a good example of that principle. You should treat sorting the list and using different layouts for each row in the list as two separate problems.

Comment: Personally I use a single layout and use gone/invisible/visible within the adapter logic e.g.  according to record type (hint `getView` provides position).

Comment: @MikeT This seems to be a solution to a different problem.